# How to control content changes under a CC BY-SA

Tags: derivative-works, copyleft

I am writing a fiction whose goal is to bring the reader to examine her/his political beliefs in the light of various political *implications* and then to arrive, on her/his own, at possibly different beliefs.

I can see two very different ways that the contents could eventually be changed by licensees:

- The kind of changes, probably fairly limited, that would be necessary to change the *political implications* and thus direct the reader towards *specific beliefs*.
- The kind of changes, probably fairly extensive, that would be necessary just to turn the text into, say, a comic strip of a comic book.

Although I have read about the CC BY-SA license, I still do not see if it would be possible to prevent the former and allow the latter?

Comment: That's not possible using a CC SA license. You either allow all changes or none. You can not specify which changes or derived works are allowed and which are forbidden.

Comment: @LutzHorn I was afraid it would be so. So, I suppose one could turn the Bible into Das Kapital. Room for another CC license?

Comment: Why do you want to prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put simply: if you want to maintain creative control over your work, don't release it under an open source license. This applies whether that license is CC-BY-SA or any other open source license. An open source license by definition allows people to make any modification they like to the content - anything else would violate the ["No Discrimination Against Fields of Endeavor" clause of the Open Source Definition](https://opensource.org/osd):

> The license must not restrict anyone from making use of the program in a specific field of endeavor. For example, it may not restrict the program from being used in a business, or from being used for genetic research.

Comment: I was not aware of the "No discrimination ..." clause. But, as I pointed out in the comment above, and even though I know perfectly well that it is hard to delineate and define, there is such a thing as turning things on their head. By the way, all my mathematics textbooks are under FDL.

Comment: @schremmer: If you don't want to be associated with a particular derived work of your story, then the CC BY-SA license explicitly gives you the right to have your credits *removed* from the derived work.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau  I hadn't thought of it. But it seems to be all I want. I will really have to read the license. Thanks.